# How to statically check if two functions that might or might not have the same signature are the same function?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, static-assert

I want to statically check whether two functions are the same one.

Something like this:

```
struct Base { void f(){} };
struct Derived1: public Base { void f(){ puts("Hey!"); } };
struct Derived2: public Base { int f(){ return 0; } };
struct Derived3: public Base {};

static_assert( &Base::f != &Derived1::f );
static_assert( &Base::f != &Derived2::f );
static_assert( &Base::f == &Derived3::f );
```

The second `static_assert` fails to compile because the signature of `Base::f` and `Derived2::f` differs:

```
error: comparison of distinct pointer types ('void (Base::*)()' and 'int (Derived2::*)()')
static_assert( &Base::f != &Derived2::f );
               ~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I tried to `static_cast` those function pointers to `void*`, `unitptr_t` or `void(Base::*)()`, but the compiler won't let me. While the result of `reinterpret_cast` is not static and can't appear in a `static_assert`.

How can I perform the check?

Any C++ standard is fine.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: I'm implementing some static polymorphism and want to statically check that every subclass static-overrides the polymorphic methods.

Comment: How could two functions with distinct signature be the same function in any case?

Comment: `int f()` doesn't override  `void f()` so, technically, that's correct (both would exist in derived class)

Comment: The [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) could be relevant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need something to reject the different signatures before trying to `==` them.

```
template <typename F1, typename F2>
constexpr bool same_function(F1, F2) { return false; }

template <typename F>
constexpr bool same_function(F f1, F f2) { return f1 == f2; }
```

[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60d86146f8e75321)